# Using trace to execute a proc in TCL

Tags: tcl, trace

I have the following in a TCL/Tk app:

```
 proc greyout { } {
     puts "current part $DSM::Part"
     switch $DSM::Part {
 Doghouse {
     for {set entry 1} {$entry<17} {incr entry} { 
         .dsm.traceCTRpart$entry  configure -state disabled
         .dsm.traceLATpart$entry  configure -state disabled
         .dsm.traceStowage$entry  configure -state disabled      
         .dsm.traceDoghouse$entry configure -state enabled}
        }
  Stowage {
     for {set entry 1} {$entry<17} {incr entry} { 
         .dsm.traceCTRpart$entry configure -state disabled
         .dsm.traceLATpart$entry configure -state disabled
         .dsm.traceStowage$entry configure -state enabled        
         .dsm.traceDoghouse$entry configure -state disabled}
        }   
     }   
 }

  trace add variable DSM::Part write greyout
```

Each time "Part" changes the trace trys to call greyout but i get the following message:

```
 wrong # args: should be "greyout"
 wrong # args: should be "greyout"
 while executing
"greyout Part {} write"
(write trace on "Part")
invoked from within
"variable Part "CTR_Partition""
(in namespace eval "::DSM" script line 3)
invoked from within.....
```

I do not understan why?! Any Help out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when a trace callback is fired, extra arguments are appended to the callback that are used to provide information about what happened to trigger the firing of the callback. Because your code is only putting a trace on a single variable, these arguments aren't very useful to you at the moment, but they help a lot in more complex situations.

The simplest way of adapting your code to handle this is to make `greyout` take an arbitrary number of arguments by using the special `args` formal argument:

```
proc greyout {args} {
    puts "current part $DSM::Part"
    ...
}
```